# apply masking in one MMoE towers

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, masking

I have a MMoE model and have two tower android and iOS

my input tensor is of length 68.

while training the model I want to train my model on all 68 features on tower android but only 40 features on tower iOS

So, I want to apply masking in tower iOS.

```
# instantiate a Keras input tensor from the entire tensor input
numeric_input_tensor = Input(name="numeric_input_tensor", shape=(len(INPUT_FEATURES),), dtype=tf.float32)
numeric_input_tensor
<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 68) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'numeric_input_tensor')>

""" MMoE """    
# Set up MMoE layer
mmoe_layers = MMoE(
    units=MMOE_LAYER_UNITS,
    num_experts=NUM_EXPERTS,
    num_tasks=2
)(numeric_input_tensor)
mmoe_layers


# android tower
android = mmoe_layers[0]
for i, nums_units in enumerate(AND_TOWER_UNITS):
    android = Dense(nums_units, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
                        kernel_regularizer=AND_REGULARIZER,
                    name=f'and_enc_dense_{i}')(android)
    android = BatchNormalization(name=f'and_enc_bn_{i}')(android)
    android = Activation('selu', name=f'and_enc_act_{i}')(android)
    android = Dropout(rate=AND_DROPOUT_RATE, name=f'and_enc_drop_{i}')(android)  

# android tower output
output_and = Dense(len(INPUT_FEATURES), activation="linear", name="and_output")(android)

# ios tower 

    ios = mmoe_layers[1]
    for i, nums_units in enumerate(IOS_TOWER_UNITS):
        ios = Dense(nums_units, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(),
                            kernel_regularizer=IOS_REGULARIZER,
                        name=f'ios_enc_dense_{i}')(ios)
        ios = BatchNormalization(name=f'ios_enc_bn_{i}')(ios)
        ios = Activation('selu', name=f'ios_enc_act_{i}')(ios)
        ios = Dropout(rate=IOS_DROPOUT_RATE, name=f'ios_enc_drop_{i}')(iOS)
    # pos tower output
    output_ios = Dense(len(INPUT_FEATURES), activation="linear", name="ios_output")(iOS)
    output_concat = concatenate([output_and, output_ios], axis=-1)

# build model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=numeric_input_tensor, outputs=output_concat)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.summary()
```

I know tf.boolean_mask will work but not sure how?
I am getting unequal dimension error?